# Accessing the Node ReadStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-stream

I have a piece of code which is wrapped in a promise. That piece of code reads an image form http, does various things, and at the end sends it to aws.s3.putObject. It looks like this (simplified):
Please note [form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty) is multiparty object.

```
form.on('part', (part) => {//form is multiparty
    fileCount++;
    let tmpFile = path.join(os.tmpDir(), `${userId}_${timePrefix}_${path.basename(part.filename)}`);
    part.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tmpFile));
    part.on('end', () => {
        resolve(fs.createReadStream(tmpFile));
    });
    part.once('error', (error) => {
        handleError(error);
    });
});

form.once('error', (error) => {
    handleError(error);
});

form.parse(request);
}).then((imageStream) => {
   //here is a call to AWS S3.putObject. Which return a promise
}).then(() => {
    return new Ok();
});
```

In essence a stream is made on a created image and sent to AWS. I wanted to do some manipulation on binary level (read file signature, to check if it is an image). I got it to work like this:

```
form.on('part', (part) => {
    fileCount++;

    let tmpFile = path.join(os.tmpDir(), `${userId}_${timePrefix}_${path.basename(part.filename)}`);
    part.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tmpFile));
    part.on('end', () => {
        let chunk = [];
        let file = fs.createReadStream(tmpFile);
        let isFirstChunkSet = false;
        file.on('data', function(chunks) {
            if (!isFirstChunkSet){
                chunk = chunks;
                isFirstChunkSet = true;
            }
        });

        file.on('close', function() {
            let magicNumber = chunk.toString('hex', 0, 2);           

            if (imageProperties.allowed_file_types.includes(magicNumber)) {
                resolve(fs.createReadStream(tmpFile));
            } else {
                error.message = 'wrong file type';
                handleError(error);
            }
        });
    });
    part.once('error', (error) => {
        handleError(error);
    });
});

form.once('error', (error) => {
    handleError(error);
});

form.parse(request);
}).then((imageStream) => {
    //here is a call to AWS S3.putObject. Which return a promise
}).then(() => {
    return new Ok();
});
```

Basically I attached two event listeners to the existing stream to access the data, and so some checking on the header file.

What bothers me is the feeling that I am overdoing things here. I would like to avoid those two listeners (data and close) and read a stream if possible.

To be more precise, this section of code receives the stream, and inside it I would like to access the data before sending it to AWS. This stream is ready, and simply put **how do I read it, without using events?**

```
form.parse(request);
}).then((imageStream) => {
    //How can I access the imageStream here, without event listeners.
    //Assumption is the stream is ready to be accessed.

    //here is a call to AWS S3.putObject. Which return a promise
}).then(() => {
    return new Ok();
});
```